# Complex Query using Multiple Columns in a single table

Tags: mysql, date, union

Let's say that I have a table of race results.  The table consists of seven columns as follows: Date ( MySql Date format of xxxx-xx-xx ), and one column each for the names of the top six finishers named First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, and Sixth.  I have a several sets of results and maybe 100 or so different names in the various finisher columns.  I need a query that would allow me to list each person whose name has appeared in any of the finisher columns ( First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth ) along with only the most recent date that their name appeared.  I do NOT need separate results based on finish place, so I need all six of the finisher columns lumped together.  Most of the names will appear on dozens of different dates, but I only need the most recent date that each name appeared.  Ideally the result would generate a list of each name and their most recent finish date, sorted from least recent to most recent.  I tried to create a fiddle to demonstrate this but for whatever reason I could not get the date to work correctly in the fiddle.  Anyway, anyone who can offer even a shred of help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is normalisation not an option?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT <table>.date, <table>.first as name FROM <table> GROUP BY name
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT <table>.date, <table>.second as name FROM <table> GROUP BY name
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT <table>.date, <table>.third as name FROM <table> GROUP BY name
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT <table>.date, <table>.fourth as name FROM <table> GROUP BY name
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT <table>.date, <table>.fifth as name FROM <table> GROUP BY name
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT <table>.date, <table>.sixth as name FROM <table> GROUP BY name
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Actually, this is close but some entries are completely skipped.  For instance, there are 104 unique names in those columns, but the query only returns 29 rows.  There should be 104 rows with the most recent date for each unique name.

Comment: I made an adjustment, it is untested as I do not have your data set but something like this.

Comment: I did some tinkering as well.  I was wrong about only showing 29 rows.  That was a typo on my part.  This query returns every row.  For instance, if "Tom Davis" appears 43 times in the result sets this query returns all 43 of those as individual rows rather than just returning the most recent.  I need only the most recent occurrence of each name.  It should return 104 rows, one for each unique name, and the most recent occurrence for each of those names.

Comment: Think I figured it out for ya this time. See my revised code.

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  I'll post the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your help, though.  I really do very much appreciate the effort.  The problem we were running into is that DISTINCT can only be used for entire rows rather than individual columns. Even using UNION DISTINCT doesn't necessarily select only the most recent Date for a given name.  I need to UNION all of the results and essentially query that result set.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me exactly the results I needed.  I basically just used "name" to catch the finishers, and "MAX(Date) as last" to pick out only the most recent showing for each "name" when I queried all six columns.

```
SELECT name, MAX(Date) as last
FROM (
SELECT first name,Date FROM Results
UNION ALL
SELECT second, Date FROM Results
UNION ALL
SELECT third, Date FROM Results 
UNION ALL
SELECT fourth, Date FROM Results
UNION ALL
SELECT fifth, Date FROM Results
UNION ALL
SELECT sixth, Date FROM Results) Q 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY last ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

select t.first, a.date from (select distinct(first) from race union select distinct(second) from race union select distinct(third) from race union select distinct(fourth) from race union select distinct(fifth) from race union select distinct(sixth) from race) as t, race a where t.first in (a.first, a.second, a.third, a.fourth, a.fifth, a.sixth)